# Is it possible for a Servlet filter to retrieve its url path?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I can map a single servlet to various url patterns in the web.xml file. When programming the servlet, I can then get which of those url patterns the request is matching, by getting the servlet path through `request.getServletPath()`.

How can I achieve this with filters? When mapping a filter to various url patterns, is there a way to get what path the current request is matching?

Because my filter is currently working on content that is mapped to the DefaultServlet, the `request.getServletPath()` returns the whole path, and PathInfo is always null.

I am a newbie on servlet and filters, so I hope my question is clear and makes sense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. You have to determine it yourself based on the request URI and a predefinied set/list/map of all known/supported paths. You can if necessary set those paths as `<init-param>` of the filter and process it during the `init()` method so that you can reuse it in the `doFilter()` method.